# Typescript - Is there any reason why the function keyword is accepted outside classes but not within it?

Tags: typescript

I just realized this situation and I am really puzzled by that.

Though it doesn't make any real difference for the application, I couldn't find any reason why something like this is accepted out of a scope of a class but not inside of it.

```
function doSomethingNice()
{
    return 'Okay';
}
```

The above works, and it's actually mandatory to use the function keyword, but the under does not:

```
export class Etc {
    function doSomethingNice() {
        return 'Whatever';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a function you have one syntax and when you define a class you have another syntax...

To define methods in a class, you just need to declare them without the function keyword.

```
export class Etc {
    doSomethingNice() {
        return 'Whatever';
    }
}
```

More about classes [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

More about functions [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html).

Comment: But that's the thing Oram, I know this syntax works without a function keyword, but I cannot understand why if you have the keyword it will trigger an error. Meaning: how come the syntax are different in this specific case?

Comment: It's arbitrary. The people who defined the specifications (for [ECMAScript 6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantics-nonconstructormethoddefinitions)) thought that adding the function keyword is unnecessary in this context.
On the other hand, when you're declaring a function you must use the function keyword or you won't be able to distinguish between declaration and invocation.